# How can I make this if else statement work with cin statements?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a program for a class involving code for a Grade Point Average calculator with added features.  My code was working right up until I added my last line of code for the sum of the grades and subsequent division for the average.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm at a loss, currently.  Ideally, this program would be accepting input from a user at four separate points, adding the input together, and then dividing it by 4 (as the current number of grades I have code for is 4, but I plan on increasing this amount once I figure out how to solve this issue).

Initially, I was getting errors because I was asking the code to translate a `double` variable into a `char` variable and then back into a `double` variable (error code C4244).  I also changed the end of the code to declare the sum of all grades as a separate variable, because including it all in one variable, `GPA`, resulted in the program outputting a seemingly random number.  I since changed my code to flow more evenly, however now when I execute the program, it asks for the initial input for the first grade then skips right over the second, third, and fourth grades.

I'm still extremely new to C++, so I may be over complicating my code, but I'm stumped.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int GPAAndHonorsCalculator;

int main()
{
    //Declaring initial values
    double A = 4.0;
    double B = 3.0;
    double C = 2.0;
    double D = 1.0;
    double F = 0.0;
    double GPA = 0.0;

    //Created if else statements to handle user input and translation into data for the program to use.
    cout << "Please enter your first grade: " << endl;
    double gradeOne = 0.0;
    cin >> gradeOne;
    if (gradeOne == 'A') {
        gradeOne = 4.0;
    }
    else if (gradeOne == 'B') {
        gradeOne = 3.0;
    }
    else if (gradeOne == 'C') {
        gradeOne = 2.0;
    }
    else if (gradeOne == 'D') {
        gradeOne = 1.0;
    }
    else if (gradeOne == 'F') {
        gradeOne = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter your second grade: " << endl;
    double gradeTwo = 0.0;
    cin >> gradeTwo;
    if (gradeTwo == 'A') {
        gradeTwo = 4.0;
    }
    else if (gradeTwo == 'B') {
        gradeTwo = 3.0;
    }
    else if (gradeTwo == 'C') {
        gradeTwo = 2.0;
    }
    else if (gradeTwo == 'D') {
        gradeTwo = 1.0;
    }
    else if (gradeTwo == 'F') {
        gradeTwo = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter your third grade: " << endl;
    double gradeThree = 0.0;
    cin >> gradeThree;
    if (gradeThree == 'A') {
        gradeThree = 4.0;
    }
    else if (gradeThree == 'B') {
        gradeThree = 3.0;
    }
    else if (gradeThree == 'C') {
        gradeThree = 2.0;
    }
    else if (gradeThree == 'D') {
        gradeThree = 1.0;
    }
    else if (gradeThree == 'F') {
        gradeThree = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter your fourth grade: " << endl;
    double gradeFour = 0.0;
    cin >> gradeFour;
    if (gradeFour == 'A') {
        gradeFour = 4.0;
    }
    else if (gradeFour == 'B') {
        gradeFour = 3.0;
    }
    else if (gradeFour == 'C') {
        gradeFour = 2.0;
    }
    else if (gradeFour == 'D') {
        gradeFour = 1.0;
    }
    else if (gradeFour == 'F') {
        gradeFour = 0.0;
    }
    int gradeSum = gradeOne + gradeTwo + gradeThree + gradeFour;
    GPA = gradeSum / 4;
    cout << GPA;
}
```

At the suggestion of @LukeH, I cleaned up my code and made a nested while switch statement.  Here is part of the working code:

```
int main() {

//Declaring initial values, as well as initializing a counter for later loop.
int gradeValue = 0;
int gradeCount = 0;
char userGrade = 0;
double GPA = 0.0;

//Creating while loop with switch statement nested inside to handle large amounts of repeating code.
while (gradeCount!= 4) {
    cout << "Please enter a grade (A, B, C, D, or F): ";
    cin >> userGrade;

    switch (userGrade) {
    case 'A': {
        gradeValue = gradeValue + 4;
        ++gradeCount;
        break;
    }
```

I repeated this process for each grade and it worked a treat!

Comment: `double` variables are not used to hold characters.

Comment: You should be storing your input as a character and not a double if you are expecting to get a letter as an input. You cannot store a character and a number in the same variable in C++, so your code is not performing properly. With that many `else if` statements as well, you may find it better to use a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp).

Comment: Also, it is a general principal in programming to try and not repeat yourself. If you look at your code, you are essentially rewriting the same thing each time you are getting a grade input. If you separated out that code into a separate function called `getGrade()` or something, you would have much cleaner code and it would be much simpler to scale the amount of input you can accept in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that, @SidS, but I thank you for pointing out the blatant error that I was apparently missing.  I'd blame it on lack of sleep or being new, but it's mostly just being completely green with C++.  

  @LukeH thank you for pointing it out as well and expanding upon how I can improve upon my code.  For the get grade function, I understand I'm creating the switch statement for cleaner code, however, would I still be using the same `cin >>` statement and assigning the numerical value as a separate variable, correct?

Comment: @LukeH, thank you very much for your help!  I will post the new product in the main question as it seems to be helping, though I'm unsure of how to mark your answer as correct?  I ended up creating a while loop and nested a switch statement inside to handle the massive amount of repeating code.  I also made use of a counter to keep track of the number of grades for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented earlier, but I figured I'd elaborate a bit more if it could help further.

As it seems you have already figured out, you were trying to store a character in a double variable which will either break your code or have some serious unexpected results. Unlike languages like Javascript, [variables in C++](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_variables.asp) have a defined type and **cannot change** between, say, a `double` and a `string`. In your edited code you seemed to have accounted for this and it seems your code is now functioning better.

One important thing to note, especially as it seems you are still learning, is there should be a little internal alarm that goes off in your head as a programmer anytime you are writing blocks of code that are the same or very similar to code you have already written. The saying "DRY" or **"Don't Repeat Yourself"** is very popular for a reason and can help your code be much easier to read, write, and edit.

For your example, the main function has all of your logic in it and as it gets longer and longer it can be hard to interpret what is happening in the written code. Your code is roughly:

```
int main() {

//Declaring initial values, as well as initializing a counter for later loop.
int gradeValue = 0;
int gradeCount = 0;
char userGrade = 0;
double GPA = 0.0;

//Creating while loop with switch statement nested inside to handle large amounts of repeating code.
while (gradeCount!= 4) {
    cout << "Please enter a grade (A, B, C, D, or F): ";
    cin >> userGrade;

    switch (userGrade) {
        case 'A': {
            gradeValue = gradeValue + 4;
            ++gradeCount;
            break;
        }
        case 'B': {
            gradeValue = gradeValue + 3;
            ++gradeCount;
            break;
        }
        case 'C': {
            gradeValue = gradeValue + 2;
            ++gradeCount;
            break;
        }
        case 'D': {
            gradeValue = gradeValue + 1;
            ++gradeCount;
            break;
        }
        case 'F': { 
            ++gradeCount; // no need to add to value since F=0
            break;
        }
    }

    // logic to display GPA
    // TODO
```

If you instead put the user input logic in its own function, your `main()` will be much cleaner. An added benefit is that if you need to update the logic for getting input (like you did once already!), your `main()` function doesn't need to change at all.

Your `main()` would look something like this then:

```
int main() {
    // declare variables
    double gradeValue = 0.0;
    int gradeCount = 0;

    // get input
    while(gradeCount < 4) {
        gradeValue += getUserGrade(); // add grade to GPA
        gradecount++;
    }

    // logic to display GPA
    // TODO
}
```

Much easier to understand right? In your `getUserGrade()` function you would just need to have your switch statement logic and return a double value of the grade they input. I left out the logic to display GPA just because this is an assignment and that part is up to you to finish.

With this simpler framework in place, you can easily adjust the code to be able to handle as many grade inputs as the user wants to give. If you just have an option for the user to type "done" or something else significant when they are asked for a grade, you can return a special value that your code in `main()` can use to know when to stop taking input (-1.0 would work because that would not be a valid GPA). Your `main()` would look something like this then:

```
int main() {
    // declare variables
    double gradeValue = 0.0;
    int gradeCount = 0;

    // get input
    while(true) {
        double usrInput = getUserGrade();

        if(usrInput == -1.0) break; // exit loop if user is done

        gradeValue += usrInput;
        gradecount++;
    }

    // logic to display GPA
    // TODO
}
```

With only changing a few lines of code, you can now have a program that is much more flexible!

Comment: Thank you so much for the added clarification, and input on making the program simpler and easier to understand!  I also greatly appreciate leaving out code for me to work on myself; as coding is learned better while doing, I have found and seems to be the best practice.  This has also helped me to better understand my code, so once again, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what are you using the variables A, B,C, D, F for?  Secondly you can't use double type variable to store characters. Just use a char variable to get the input grade and set the grade variable accordingly. Also if you plan to add more of these grades, then it will be better for you to either write it in a function and call it again and again(or put the function call in a loop) so that repetition of code is avoided and the code in general looks cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, @amankapoor.  I appreciate the feedback on keeping my code clean as it's something I'm trying to get a hang of.  So essentially I would write the function, and store the numerical value as a separate, `double` variable instead?

Comment: yes,store the numerical value in double type variable and use another char type variable for the input of grade. then assign the numerical grade value according to the character of the grade. for eg, for 'A' put 4.0 and so on. You have to use two different variables for character and numerical value. You cant use the same variable for both.